# Solr sort within group by proximity

Tags: solr

I've got a Solr instance containing variable product prices that powers a site search. To search around a date and show results even if the exact requested date is not available, we use a query like this:

```
product_id: 759 AND arrival_date:[2016-05-20T00:00:00Z-3DAYS TO 2016-05-20T00:00:00Z+3DAYS]
```

The results are `grouped` by `product_id`. The grouping inherits a `price asc` sorting order from the main query.

This, unfortunately, has the negative side effect of always returning documents with the lowest price, regardless of the date, even if the requested date *is* available.

How can I sort within a group by proximity to a date?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `group.sort=arrival_date desc`

Alternatively if you want to sort all results based on the date first then the price us `&sort=date desc,price asc`

Comment: That would result in always having the `date-3DAYS` being sorted first, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not read your question correctly. Perhaps you can try using a boost query instead of sorting to order your results. Something like `{!boost b=(recip(ms(arrival_date,2016-05-20T00:00:00.000),2.592e-9,1,1))}product_id: 759 AND arrival_date:[2016-05-20T00:00:00.000-3DAYS TO 2016-05-20T00:00:00.000+3DAYS]`. I am not sure if this will work since I haven't tried it but you could give it a shot and post the result. Picked it up from [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Date_Boosting)

Comment: That didn't directly work, but it put me on the right track! The boost function you described can be used with `eDisMax`. I'll post more results when I finish implementing.

Comment: As promised: [Apache Solr - Group by date proximity](http://refreshless.com/blog/solr-group-date-proximity-edismax/).